# Firefox Address Bar Search Returns Web Server Running?

Tags: firefox

When I type "trends" in Firefox 25.0 address bar, it returns what looks like a web server running on my PC, although I am not running a web server.  I don't have the score to post the screen shot, but specifically it says:

> It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server
>   software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Why would this display, instead of the normal behavior of the search engine?  I'm using Windows 7 with the Anaconda Python distribution installed, but there is no Python interpreter fired up.

Comment: What happens if you ping "trends"? Is it perhaps a hostname on your local network? You can also type something like "current trends" or "2013 trends" to force a web search instead of a hostname resolution.

Comment: How about if you search for other keywords?

Comment: @ Enigma.  I believe this is what's happening.  Seems like a bad name for an alias, but I don't know much about servers.

Comment: @Darius.  No other keywords trigger the effect.

Comment: @Stix you don't happen to be using OpenDNS do you...?